# Realm Kotlin not in schema

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

I try to use **Realm.io** to store data in android i have `RealmClass`

```
@RealmClass
public open class Alarm : RealmObject() {
   @Required
   public open var hourOfDay: Int? = null
   @Required
   public open var minute: Int? = null
   @Required
   public open var days: BooleanArray? = null

   public open var name: String? = null
}
```

and in `onCreate` i try to add some test data

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mRealm = Realm.getInstance(activity);

    mRealm.beginTransaction()

    var a = mRealm.createObject(Alarm::class.java)
    a.hourOfDay = 12
    a.minute = 1;
    a.days = booleanArrayOf(true, true, true, true, true, false, false);
    a.name = "Test${System.currentTimeMillis()}"

    mRealm.commitTransaction()
}
```

but i get exception.

```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Alarm is not part of the schema for this Realm
```

at `var a = mRealm.createObject(Alarm::class.java)`

i have set realm rules

```
-keep class io.realm.annotations.RealmModule
-keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
-keep class io.realm.internal.Keep
-keep @io.realm.internal.Keep class *
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn io.realm.**
```

in **> proguard-rules.pro**

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
    realmFlavor {
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

but this did not bring solution

**CONCLUSION**

so far its looks like we have to write models in Java, Realm and any ORM libraries Kotlin examples posted on GitHub have models written in pure Java

Comment: You have set the proguard but your not enable it                                         release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

Comment: still throwing exception

Comment: Add realm rules in pro-guard file

Comment: i had done it before

Comment: add one line -keep class io.realm.annotations.RealmModule

Comment: realm doc already said to add this line, i posted my proguard file

Comment: Are you sure you enabled the annotation processing?

Comment: i can not find annotation processing in android studio setting

Answer (score 2):

"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/realm/annotations/RealmClass"

If you run into the error above, You'll most likely have to add something like this to your build.gradle. The bottom two lines for kapt are key.

```
//Realm
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.1'
kapt "io.realm:realm-annotations:0.87.1"
kapt "io.realm:realm-annotations-processor:0.87.1"
```

Per the comment at the bottom of this issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/509

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin to work with Realm's annotation processor you need the following setup in your `build.gradle`

```
compile "io.realm:realm-android-library:0.86.0@aar"
compile "io.realm:realm-annotations:0.86.0"
kapt "io.realm:realm-annotations-processor:0.86.0"
```

Comment: gradle throw `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/realm/annotations/RealmClass`

Comment: It is still necessary to use `kapt "io.realm:realm-annotations-processor:$realm_version"
    kapt "io.realm:realm-annotations:$realm_version"
` for make Realm work with Kotlin?

Comment: No, we add that automatically when you use the Realm plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I added `@RealmClass` to all models and fixed despite that [it is not required](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1283#issuecomment-120329940).

I think it forces to run Realm processor correctly by using annotator.

To check RealmObject models are processed or not, your Gradle console output (you can open it in Android Studio at the right bottom toggle panel) has to show *Red-colored model processing* log as below.

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Full recompilation is required because at least one of the classes of removed jar 'kotlin-stdlib-1.0.0.jar' requires it. Analysis took 1.572 secs.

Note: Processing class ModelSomething
Note: Processing class ModelAnotherThing
Note: Creating DefaultRealmModule
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

:app:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug
```

The `Note:` lines are red colors and you can see `Processing class ModelSomething` message.

All of your model should be listed as this message.

This issue is filed as a suspicious bug: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2822